# Format a decimal to remove trailing zeros and have a thousandths separator

Tags: c#, string-formatting, number-formatting

I have currently code that calculates decimal values based on SQL query summation. I would like this value to be formatted in such a way that it has 2 decimal places when needed, and 0 when it is a whole number. In addition to this, I also want to keep a thousandths separator.

Example:

```
 string value1 = "1234.00"
 string value2 = "1234.56"

//my goal
//parsed = 1,234
//parsed2 = 1,234.56
```

I have tried a number of variations of formatting with no luck. What is the proper syntax for this?

Huge thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your code! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you really using the same symbol for your decimal and thousands separator? That sounds like it could get very confusing very fast.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever apologies, I made a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that you cant format strings as numbers correctly, they have to be numeric types. You can use `double.TryParse` / `double.Parse` to make numeric types from a string if need be.

But the format you're looking for is `#,000.##`

```
var value1 = 1234.00;
var value2 = 1234.56;
var format = "#,###.##";
Console.WriteLine(value1.ToString(format)); // 1,234
Console.WriteLine(value2.ToString(format)); //1,234.56
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YoYcP0

Full details of [custom numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) and [standard numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: This did not work. It formatted did not keep the decimal and formatted non-triple digit numbers as 011 instead of 11.

Comment: @MarcPfister "It formatted did not keep the decimal" - this fragment doesn't make sense. On the next bit change the `0` to `#` to make all digits optional, so `#,###.##` - read the links to the docs I posted for more info

Comment: Actually it is working for the decimal apologies, just need single and 2 digit numbers to remove the leading zero.